# New Google sign in Android

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-identity

I'm trying to get a user token ID using the new Google play services 8.3
and as documented I pass the server ID:

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
    .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.server_client_id))
    .requestEmail()
    .build();
```

but I'm still getting un successful result as below:

```
{statusCode=unknown status code: 12501, resolution=null}
```

and documented here [`GoogleSignInStatusCodes`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInStatusCodes)

> The sign-in was cancelled by the user. i.e. the user cancelled some of the sign-in resolutions, e.g. account picking or OAuth consent.
>
> Constant Value: 12501

That is not my case, as I already picked an account. Any idea what could be the reason?

Comment: Note that the same status code (12501) is returned when trying to process result from a cancelled sign in dialog (`resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED`). Using GMS 8.4.0.

Comment: Finally, I made it work for me after struggling for almost a week:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33583326/new-google-sign-in-android/37657942#37657942

Comment: Please be aware that the same code 12501 may occur for a more trivial reason, i.e. lack of Internet connectivity.

Comment: @ris8_allo_zen0 I also got 12501 for  lack of Internet connectivity

Answer (score 120):

I had exactly the same problem and i have found the solution.

If you follow the documentation found here:
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating

The first step tells you to create the configuration file (which creates an OAuth 2.0 client ID for you and inserts it into the google-services.json)

Then later, it says again about creating a OAuth 2.0 client ID, but this time it says that you have to do it for **Web application**

And this is the confusing part! (at least for me) because i was just taking the client id created for the android OAuth and not creating a new one for Web application (I thought the documentation was just redundant or something)

As it says, it is this one, and only this one the one you have to use as a parameter of the methods *requestIdToken* or *requestServerAuthCode*.

Forget about using the Android OAuth ID in this methods because then you will get all the time the ugly status code response 12501.

I think the main problem is that the documentation is a bit confusing about this. Or maybe because it is a bit strange the fact that you have to create two OAuth IDs.

So as a summary, **you need TWO OAuth IDs, one for android and one for web application, and you have to set each one in the correct place.**

Comment: I had no luck. First I got a 12500 status code. Then I replaced the production hash key with the debug hash key in the google-services.json and now I get the 12501.

Comment: Now I followed exactly what @angelsages wrote. Now I get `Result: Status{statusCode=INTERNAL_ERROR, resolution=null}`.

Comment: I posted my solution below.

Comment: @Kaizie when you say '**and you have to set each one in the correct place**' what do you exactly means? I finally not using Android Client ID anywhere.

Comment: @josealfonsomora Android client key will go inside the google-services.json, and the web application key needs to be set in the requestIdToken or requestServerAuthCode methods.

Comment: I previously had a working app with google sign-in but the second one I created was not configured correctly due to the fact that I was signed in to Google with two accounts simultaneously. I had to sign out completely and go through the wizard again, add my debug certificate fingerprint and the JSON would then generate correctly.

Comment: Thanks for this MUCH NEEDED explanation. Surely, Android's documentation are always somewhat confusing.

Comment: THANKS... for this "Android client key will go inside the google-services.json, and the web application key needs to be set in the requestIdToken or requestServerAuthCode methods"

Comment: How does this web application key look like? Something like:
xxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com?
I find the sdk from google maybe the most confusing over complicated structures ever

Comment: @GillisHaasnoot Inside the google-services.json file you will find one json array called "oauth_client". Inside it you will have some client ids (as many as you have in your api console for this project) and in my case they all look the same... but the key to identify them is the field "client_type".             3=web application key

Comment: Question about the `google-services.json` file: the documentation says it's not necessary if you're just doing login. Do you actually need it no matter what?

Comment: It really says that? I cannot see how it is not needed if the oauth API key is placed inside...

Comment: As to the WebApplication OAuth2 id, This may not be necessary for you.  If you do not need to authenticate with a separate web application, or call google apis from a separate web application, you do not need to add the Web Application Auth ID. see https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating#get_your_backend_servers_oauth_20_client_id

Comment: Adding `.requestServerAuthCode` with `Web Client` ID solved my problem.

Comment: I had same issue but one thing that was missing is SHA-1 fingerprint for app in firebase

Comment: Does anybody know whats wrong if I get this error only on one device(Xiaomi mi note2) and on others devices sign in works well. I suppose that it doesn't connected to using different client Ids.

Comment: @Kaizie would there be any use of implementing redirect URI at the server in this case? I mean if your app is gonna catch the redirect URI and sending the authcode to the server for further process then the server doesn't need to collect any information from the redirect URI.

Comment: The point mentioned here actually worked. Documentation is too confusing and there isn't any straight forward explanation about the Client IDs and where we need them. I was missing android client ID and once created manually I could see the change in google-services.json file and finally it worked. Thanks a lot for the detail. You saved a lot of time.

Comment: Hi, in my case, two IDs are correctly set on console. My issue is that 12501 error occurs intermittently - sometimes sign in succeeds while sometimes not. What could be the possible cause? Anyone had the same issue?

Answer (score 21):

I was struggling with this and wasted almost a week in it.

**This is how I got it worked.**

1. Import Project in AndroidStudio
2. Create debug keystore for project.
3. Create SHA1 signature for project using debug keystore.
4. Using SHA1 signature, register your app for Google Signin on Google Developer Console.
5. Generate a Google Configuration file there.(Put in Android Studio's app folder)
6. Use Web Client ID from OAuth 2.0 credentials in your Android Project.
7. **Now, from Android Studio, generate debug build(APK) of your project.**
8. **Mount the device in your system -> copy this signed debug version of APK and install it.**

Last three **steps 6, 7 and 8**, are what you actually need to take care of. ***If you directly run the project then APK is not actually signed with the debug keystore and google does not recognise it at all.***

Comment: Could you explain please p.5 (Put in Android Studio's app folder) Which one?

Comment: And how do ypu think, can be a reason in this case : i have generate my SHA1 key for google console on one laptop, and then build my debag APK in Android Studio on other laptop. It means that Studio being process build APK use SHA1 from another laptop. But as far as i undestand google matche SHA1 from APK and SHA1 which has been registreted... Or not?

Comment: You should create a debug.keystore key and then use it everytime to sign the apk, no matter which system you are using. Just sign it.

Comment: @Master : Thanks, Man.
I was installing the apk using USB. That was my issue.
Fixed now. Thanks.

Comment: I had this one quite some time ago. This time I figured it out quickly. It was the missing SHA1 hash after switching my development machine.

Answer (score 17):

I had the same problem, after research solution it's resumed that server_client_id contained some incorrect value or your google_services.json didn't include oauth_client with client_id that registered with your keystore.

```
requestIdToken(getString(R.string.server_client_id))
```

`R.string.server_client_id` use OAuth 2.0 client ID for **Web Application**. And OAuth Client ID for **Android** use in google_services.json

Usually we use 2 keystore, 1 using debug keystore and 1 using signed keystore for published. So if we want to need in debug & publish mode, register your OAuth Client ID for Android twice, 1 using SHA1 from debug keystore and 1 from signed keystore for published.

small example in my google_services.json

```
  "oauth_client": [
    {
      "client_id": "xxx-client-id.com",
      "client_type": 1,
      "android_info": {
        "package_name": "com.app.android",
        "certificate_hash": "xxxhash"
      }
    },
    {
      "client_id": "yyy.client-id.com",
      "client_type": 1,
      "android_info": {
        "package_name": "com.app.android",
        "certificate_hash": "yyyhash"
      }
    }
  ],
```

Comment: Make sure your package name matches exactly as found in AndroidManifest.xml! That gave me a lot of headaches.

Comment: If you remove it after you've published the signed apk, it will break development. How will you be able to continue to develop your app?

Comment: @ChrisHarrison Yeah, you're right. i'm updating the answer.

Answer (score 15):

I was getting the same issue, it was because I created client ID of application type Android

[image]

Instead, I deleted it and created client ID of type web application and I got rid of this issue.

Comment: Could you had a precision to know in which screen do you find this view please ?

Comment: Not sure why this works over selecting Android, but it did for me as well.  @DanyPoplawec this is in the developer console, API Manager for a given project, you click on credentials on the left menu and then click the Create credentials button and select OAuth client ID, and you should see this page.

Answer (score 8):

Just figure out how to solve this... I was getting this error while trying to run the debug version of my app... To fix it, add a credential for your debug app on the developer console and also on the google-services.json.

this fixed it for me!

Comment: Could you provide some detail on how you did this? This could be my problem too.

Comment: @JDenais, go to the Google developers console > Api Manager > Credentials, create a Auth 2.0 Android Credential with the signing certificate you use to generate the debug version (debug.keystore on your computer probably), and the degub package name of your app.. after that, add this Client Id to the google-services.json, something like this: "oauth_client":[ {":"XXXX","client_type":1, "android_info":{"package_name":"com.fleeber", certificate_hash":"YYYYYYY"}},{"client_id":"XXX", client_type":1,"android_info":{"package_name":"com.fleeber.debug","certificate_hash":"YYYY"}}]

Comment: I previously had a working app with google sign-in but the second one I created was not configured correctly due to the fact that I was signed in to Google with two accounts simultaneously.  I had to sign out completely and go through the wizard again, add my debug certificate fingerprint and the JSON would then generate correctly.

Comment: Wow, you literally just helped me out after more than 5 hours of endless searching online. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem, and I solved with the following solution:

1. Create configuration file (google-services.json) as described [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating#get-config) and place in your /app project directory
2. (As mentioned in other answers) Using Web application Client ID for `requestIdToken` method.
3. [My main problem] Sign your app if you work on debug mode like below:

> ```
>  signingConfigs {
>     release {
>         storeFile file("myreleasekey.keystore")
>         storePassword "password"
>         keyAlias "MyReleaseKey"
>         keyPassword "password"
>     }
>  }
>
>  buildTypes {
>      release {
>          ...
>      }
>      debug {
>          ...
>          signingConfig signingConfigs.release
>      }
>  }
> ```

Answer (score 4):

Now I got it.

So first you must follow the upper answers saying:

1. create a OAuth client-id for web applications in the Google Developers Console and use it in `requestIdToken()`
   (get rid of status code 12501)
2. if you created a Android OAuth client-id for your production hash key, create a new Android OAuth client-id for your debug hash key and integrate it into your google-services.json.
   (get rid of status code 12500)

**No longer valid**
And here comes the last Part:
 3. you can not call `requestIdToken()` and `requestEmail()` at once. At least in my case I got rid of `Result: Status{statusCode=INTERNAL_ERROR, resolution=null}` by deleting `requestEmail()`.

So good luck...

Comment: The thing in your part 3 is surely wrong. `requestIdToken()` and `requestEmail()` can be used at once. I am using it successfully in my app.

Comment: Then there must be another difference between our projects. Because in my project it works exactly as described.

Comment: I agree, I am using both `requestIdToken()` and `requestEmail()` at once. There is no problem with that.

Comment: Maybe it was a problem with one library version. It's gone.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I also had to check that the debug SHA-1 was added as a valid OAuth Android client.

Comment: `12501` is always a configuration error.  Along with the case you mentioned here, an invalid server client ID or a package name mismatch will cause this as well.

Answer (score 3):

Use **Web application** as server_client_id not Android application

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I noticed that 12501 code was returned when my `server_client_id` contained some incorrect value.

Since there is no detailed message and the documentation of this error code is rather poor I don't know if your problem has the same cause as mine.

---

My application is based on Android code from [this example](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/signin) (class IdTokenActivity).
To make it work I also needed to [integrate Google sign-in](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating) into my app:

- generated json config file with enabled Google Sign-In
- added Google plugin and dependency to my gradle file
- created OAuth client ID for this app and saved it in my project as `server_client_id`

Comment: I don't think that the servier_id isn't correct. I tried different ones .

Answer (score 2):

Is your apk in debug mode? I think it only works with a signed apk.

Answer (score 2):

1. Follow the ambiguous google's document.
2. Put google-services.json to your project directory
3. Set your gradle as https://stackoverflow.com/a/35216421/5886475
4. Set server_client_id in string.xml .It's your **web client id** not android client

Comment: **Yes**, that 4. helped me plus [whitelisting it](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/d9MHQjAxFBY)

Answer (score 2):

A problem I had is that the SHA-1 I generated as with the incorrect alias.
The alias **MUST BE androiddebugkey** .
So I have put the Android OAuth ID at my *google-service.json* file. I have put the Web Client Id to *requestIdToken()*.
And in my specific case, I generated the SHA-1 with **androiddebugkey** alias.

**google-services.json**:

```
"oauth_client": [
    {
      "client_id": "ANDROID OAUTH ID-.....apps.googleusercontent.com",
      "client_type": 1,
      "android_info": {
        "package_name": "br.com.packagename",
        "certificate_hash": "SHA-1 HASH"
      }
    },{
      "client_id": "WEB CLIEND ID......apps.googleusercontent.com",
      "client_type": 3
    }
 ]
```

**Signing part:**

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken("WEB CLIEND ID......apps.googleusercontent.com")
                .requestEmail() 
                .build();
```

Comment: thanks man. I got lost till I understand I must use androiddebugkey and not custom debug key

Answer (score 2):

In place of `R.string.server_client_id` , just use `R.string.default_web_client_id` .

When you copy the **google-services.json** file into the app, it creates this string value automatically. You don't need to copy the key from google-services.json to string.xml
It worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue by Clicking Firebase Support in Android Studio, which may not be relevant to non-Firebase users.

1. Go to menu Tools->Firebase
2. Click Connect your app to Firebase, it will display as Connected in green once connection is successful
3. Click Add Firebase Authentication to your app button, it will also turn green.

NOTE: Having huge list of answers in this definitely confirm one thing. Google needs to update and keep the documentation fool proof.

Answer (score 1):

If none of the above options work, do check whether you applicationId in app build.gradle is same as you package name.

Answer (score 1):

Oviously first check your release sha1 key is correct or not. But if still it is not working and you ar using google play services 8.4.0 (i.e.compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'), the issue could be solved by modifying GoogleSignInOption object.
Instead of:

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                    .requestEmail()  
       .requestIdToken("YOUR_WEB_API_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com")
                    .build();
```

You have to use :

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN))
                .requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.PLUS_ME))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
```

This solves error returning statusCode=INTERNAL_ERROR OR statusCode=Error 12501 OR statusCode=Error 12500.
Then this gso object could be used for creating GoogleApiClient as shown below:

```
 mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this, this)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API,gso)
               // .addApi(Plus.API, null)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
               // .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
                .build();
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't know why but SHA1 in android studio is changed automatically and that's why I am getting this error. To solve this I updated the SHA1 of my firebase project settings with the new SHA1 of my android studio and it started working again.

Comment: I am using firebase so updated SHA1 there but somebody using google console then it needs to update acordingly.

Comment: I changed work laptops and couldn't figure out why Google sign in wasn't working for me anymore. Then I remembered my new laptop must have different SHA-1 fingerprint and that it must be added in the Google Developer Console.

Comment: so now ur issue fixed

Answer (score 1):

In my case, my Credentials for `Client ID for Android` on [Google APIs Console](http://console.developers.google.com) only contained the SHA-1 for my *release signed APK*. Android Studio was using the *default debug keystore* to sign my debug builds, and in that case the debug keystore SHA-1 did *not* match the Android client SHA-1 online. My solution was to simply sign the debug builds with the release keystore.

In Android Studio, `Build/Edit Build Types...`, then select your debug build type and make sure Signing Config is set to your release certificate.

[image: Signing Config set to release]

Comment: Thank you so much for this palm to head moment. \\\, (-.-)  >>>  ///(-.-)

Comment: I should mention that I was actually getting a different error code. I was getting an 10 DEVELOPER_ERROR, but this was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and error **12501** and non of of above did work for me.

My problem was I using *google Default web api* that generated for me. after creating my own web api error disappeared and worked fine!

these are working steps:

1. first I created SHA1 debug key and add to **Firebase** console. creating SHA1 from [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth).
2. create both web api and android OAuth 2.0 client ID from [here](https://console.developers.google.com/projectselector/apis/credentials)
3. get generated `google-service.json` from **Firebase** console and put in app folder.
4. put this code for `GoogleSignnOption`

like this:

```
gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN).requestIdToken
                ("put the web app client Id that get from the link in developer console ")
                .requestEmail().build();
```

**tip 1:** I find out that you should create both android and web app Client Id to work.

**tip 2:** if you from Iran like me you can get the user from google but you can not `AuthWithGoogle` and result will `fail` in `auth.signInWithCredential(credential)` and you had to use some proxy for returning true.

this is the working full source of FireBaseAuthDemo in github:

[image]

hope help full

Comment: Did you use the same redirect Uri's as those which were set up in the web application created automatically? I'm experiencing this problem as well and it's driving me mad!

Comment: what should be the value of "client_type" in auth client? 
you have declared   "client_type": 1 and as well as  "client_type": 3. 
What does it signify ?

Comment: @JohnMc I put the whole test app in here https://github.com/mahdit83/FireBaseAuthDemo

Comment: @rajat44 That file is auto generated from google console and really do not know how google handle that file. but this is the way you can make it works.

Answer (score 1):

Try following these steps:

1. Clone the following project https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services
2. Follow the guide at https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start
3. Use Web client (auto created by Google Service) and add it in requestIdToken(...)

   ```
   GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
      .requestEmail()  
      .requestIdToken("YOUR_WEB_API_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com")
      .build();
   ```
4. Make sure you are using the same keystore used which is added to Google project. For instance, if you have used the following command to generate SHA-1 key

   ```
   keytool -exportcert -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore
   ```
5. Then add the following code in app/build.gradle file inside android { ... } [Solved my problem]

   ```
   signingConfigs
   {
       debug 
       {
           storeFile file("/home/ashwin/.android/debug.keystore")
           storePassword "android"
           keyAlias "androiddebugkey"
           keyPassword "android"
       }
   }

   buildTypes
   {
       release
       {
           minifyEnabled false
           proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
       }
       debug
       {
           signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
       }
   }
   ```

Note: Your keyPassword and keyAlias should be the same used during generation of SHA-1 certificate.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the **debug keystore** to build the project, you need to add the SHA-1 fingerprint of **debug.keystore** on **Firebase Console**.

1. On your **Firebase Console**, open your Project
2. Go to Parameters. Tab **General**
3. At the end of this page, there is a field to add a **Fingerprint SHA-1**
4. Paste the SHA-1 in the console field.

To obtain SHA-1 of debug.keystore :

**Mac/Linux :**

```
keytool -exportcert -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore
```

**Windows :**

```
 keytool -exportcert -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore
```

https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth

That's all !

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, after following Google's instructions for [Automatically signing your app](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#sign-auto).  If you are using this method to sign your apps, you will need to include the generated keystore fingerprint in your API credentials.

> On the project browser, right click on your app and select Open Module
>   Settings.

[image: Screenshot of Open Module Settings | app | signing | config]

I found it less confusing to put the `.jks` file in my project's `/app` directory.  In any case run this line on it.

```
keytool -list -v -keystore /home/user/keystores/android.jks
```

You will be prompted for a password.  Not sure if it's the `Key Password` or `Store Password` because mine are the same.  :|

The console will spit out a bunch of certificate fingerprints.  Take the SHA1 one and punch it into your API credentials at the [Google API Developer's Console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis).  You will need to enter it for the Android client `OAuth 2.0 client IDs` even though you don't actually use that client_id in your app.  If you are using other APIs for android, put the same SHA1 in the appropriate key credentials under `API keys` too.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a new one. I was trying for 6 hours to login on the emulator with the id from my corporate Google Apps domain, to no avail, getting 12501 errors. On a hunch, I tried my personal gmail id and it worked. Ditto if I tried on my phone with my corporate id. It turns out the emulator did not have the proper Mobile Device Management settings to allow my corporate id to login.

So If I want to test on the emulator with this corporate id, I have to install Google Play Store, then the MDM software, and configure it.

Answer (score 0):

From my weird experience with this error, I can say that you also need to try to reboot your phone in order to get rid of this error :)
I was implemented Google Sign In using G Suite accounts which have a device policy assigned via Google Admin. So on the first sign in it was requiring to install Device Policy app. After all later steps completed, it was just throwing 12501 error. Same time the same app was working fine on other phones. So only reboot helped. But helped

Answer (score 0):

Though already many upvoted answers exist in this question, I  struggled to understand the logic.
So, I come up with my research.

- Create a app using correct **package name** & Signing-certificate fingerprint **SHA-1** https://developers.google.com/mobile/add?platform=android&cntapi=signin
- Enable google sign-in
- Generate the configuration file.

To get SHA-1, run this in terminal:

```
keytool -exportcert -keystore path-to-debug-or-production-keystore -list -v
```

About `OAuth 2.0 client IDs`

- OAuth for the web (In app this is used as `server_client_id`)
- OAuth for android (This needs to be created using correct **package name** & Signing-certificate fingerprint **SHA-1**).

> If you are using the different keystore for debug & release, you need to create separate `OAuth 2.0 client IDs` using respective *package name* & *SHA-1*.

You can create or edit your `OAuth 2.0 client IDs` here  https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=

1. Navigating to your app.
2. If you already have a OAuth for Android, click in its name & check the *package name* & *SHA-1*.

We can use the same keystore for both debug & release by saving the keystore details in global(local, not inside project) `gradle.properties` & getting it in `build.gradle` as below.

```
def key_alias = ""
def key_password = ""
def store_file = ""
def store_password = ""

try {
    key_alias = YOUR_KEY_ALIAS
    key_password = YOUR_KEY_PASSWORD
    store_file = YOUR_KEYSTORE_PATH
    store_password = YOUR_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD
} catch (Exception exception) {
    throw new IllegalStateException('Failed to find key store details. Social Login is disabled');
}

android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias key_alias
            keyPassword key_password
            storeFile file(store_file)
            storePassword store_password
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
            // ...
        }
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

You can use below snippet

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_GOOGLE_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            // ...
        } else if (result.getStatus().getStatusCode() == CommonStatusCodes.NETWORK_ERROR) {
            // No internet connection
        } else if (result.getStatus().getStatusCode() == CommonStatusCodes.DEVELOPER_ERROR) {
            // Wrong server OAuth key(server_client_id)
        } else if (result.getStatus().getStatusCode() == 12501) {
            // Wrong app signing-certificate fingerprint SHA1
        } else {
            Log.e("Google sign in error", result.getStatus().toString());
        }
    }
}
```

> Note: If you enabled only Google Sign-In when you generated the configuration file, you need not to add the `google-servies.json` file in your project.(generating the file performs the necessary configuration steps).

Answer (score 0):

**1.Specify signingConfigs in your gradle file**

```
signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias 'appalias'
            keyPassword 'hunter123'
            storePassword 'hunter123'
            storeFile file('path/to/keystore.jks')
        }
}
```

**2.Go to Build Types in Project Structure (in Android Studio) and specify signingConfigs to "config"**

Now **clean** your project and build again. It should work.

If the above doesn't work then below is your last resort.
Try step one and build and check. If it's not working go to next step and try to build again.

1. Build a signed apk (With remember password checked).
2. Before signing check the filename of the keystore file and the one yo give in while signing the apk (in android studio).
3. Install the signed apk in your device.
4. Wait for five minutes.
5. Try singing in to google. If still 12501 is coming wait five more minutes. While doing that hit gradle sync.
6. Try again. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

Since the app requests Google sign in from web view we need to create web application auth client id v2.0

1. Go to [Google API Credentials](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials) and Choose your Android project from Top Left corner [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3s7j.png)
2. Click on Create Credentials --> OAuth Client Id --> Choose Web
   Application
3. Click Ok
4. Now , if you have synced Android Studio with Firebase (logged in)
   just rebuild the project  Otherwise Download updated
   **google-services.json** file and replace the existing one.

It should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem too, Was resolved as follows:

> 1. I was made to delete the SHA1 previously thought and create and set new SHA1.
> 2. generate new `google-services.json` and set into my app directory
> 3. I was use exactly [google developer codes](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating)
> 4. my `result.isSucces()` returned true after running the project

**as summary, delete old sha1 and create new sha1 and download new google-services.json**

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same `12501 status` error. This is due to SHA-1 mismatch of release APK and debug APK.

1. Make a signed APK. To sign an APK, choose existing path of the keystore you have used for creating SHA-1. e.g. `/.android/debug.keystore`
2. Give alias-name : androiddebugkey
3. storepass and keypass : android.

Answer (score 0):

I have developed lib to Add Google SignIn option in your app with just few lines of code. Try [HiGoogle- Google SignIn Made Easy](https://shivam301296.github.io/HiGoogle/)

Use **Web application** as server_client_id not Android application. Pass it in the HiGoogle constructor.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem. I probably didn't follow the steps properly when I first created the google-services.json and added firebase to project, and even after trying all the steps described here I couldn't fix the problem.
I finally managed by connecting to firebase from within android studio as described [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/firebase.html). I went through the first two steps and compiled again, the code finally worked.