# Google sign in failed after frequent signing in and out

Tags: android, google-play-services

I can sign in my app with Google account at first several times.
Everything is fine.

But if I sign in and out about 20 times in a one or two minutes.
Google sign in failed and in `onActivityResult` function, it returns error code 12501, resultCode = 0;

I'm using the phone: Nexus 6, Android 5.1.1

Here is my code：

```
private GoogleSignInOptions mGso;
private GoogleApiClient mGac;

public void init(@NonNull final BaseActivity activity) {
    mGso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(activity.getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    mGac = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(activity)
            .enableAutoManage(activity /* FragmentActivity */, new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
                    ToastUtils.show(activity, R.string.login_failed);
                }
            })
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, mGso)
            .build();
}

public void signIn(@NonNull final BaseActivity activity,
                   @NonNull GoogleSignInCallback callback,
                   @NonNull final OnLoadingListener<PlatformUserEntity> listener) {

    callback.registerCallback(listener);
    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGac);
    activity.startActivityForResult(signInIntent, REQUEST_GOOGLE_SIGNIN);

    // disconnect the client
    mGac.stopAutoManage(activity);
    mGac.disconnect();

}
```

Here is gradle:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.6.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.6.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.6.1'
```

Fisrt, I init the GoogleApiClient with a FragmentActivity, then signIn function starts the Acitvity. GoogleSignInCallback is registered in the onActivityResult function. Then disconnect the Client because every time the sign in button is clicked, the init function will be invoked.

I doubt that I use `stopAutoManage()` too early but it seems like not true.
So I'm confused, which part might be wrong?

I noticed the log:

```
Could not set socket write timeout: null
12-03 17:21:43.859 264-264/? W/SurfaceFlinger: couldn't log to binary event log: overflow.
12-03 17:21:43.902 1946-12870/? W/Conscrypt: Could not set socket write timeout: null
12-03 17:21:44.327 21168-21168/? W/AccountChipsFragment: Recording consent failed.
12-03 17:21:44.657 29359-29782/? E/TokenRequestor: You have wrong OAuth2 related configurations, please check. Detailed error: UNREGISTERED_ON_API_CONSOLE
12-03 17:21:44.664 812-1072/? W/ActivityManager: getRunningAppProcesses: caller 10145 does not hold REAL_GET_TASKS; limiting output
12-03 17:21:44.697 21168-21168/? W/AutoManageHelper: Unresolved error while connecting client. Stopping auto-manage.
```

It said "You have wrong OAuth2 related configuration", but I could use the web client id to request the IdToken at the first time.

It just makes me more confused.

I also found a strange thing. If I install the apk which is built locally, this error never happened. If I download from google play store, this error ocurred. But there is no difference between these two apks because I deliver google store with the local one.

Comment: paste your logcat

Comment: @RavishSharma i post my logcat but can't figure out why it happens

Comment: http://www.androidwarriors.com/2016/02/google-plus-integration-in-android-sign.html please check this link ...it may help You

Comment: @RavishSharma OK  thanks

Comment: You welcome......

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Finally I found the reason.
My apk was signed again by our company's release procedure. 
The procedure used another keystore so my sha1 key was changed.
I configure the new sha1 key in google develop console, this bug is solved.

But I'm still confused that, if I use the debug keystore apk, got sign in successfully and uninstall it, then I install the google play apk which has different sha1 key, google sign in can work some times.It won't tell me wrong immediately.

Comment: This could be a rookie question, but could you describe where you can configure the sha1 key in the google dev console?

Comment: @XavierPortebois Yes, I have no idea about the release procedure by our company.         I use firebase cloud messaging, the sha1 key is set in the console of [firebase](console.firebase.google.com).  Or you can configure it at [here](https://developers.google.com/mobile/add?platform=android) if you don't need firebase.

Comment: I found that after a little struggle. I never read in the "sign your app" doc that you have to register the signed APK through the dev console, but anyway, now it's done. 

For people with the same problem, if you're still stuck, you could check my own step-by-step, maybe it could help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41012703/923712

Answer (score 0):

if your code working well at first time then
you can try that way,

```
private GoogleSignInOptions mGso;
private GoogleApiClient mGac;

public void signIn(@NonNull final BaseActivity activity,
           @NonNull GoogleSignInCallback callback,
           @NonNull final OnLoadingListener<PlatformUserEntity> listener) {

    mGso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(activity.getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    mGac = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(activity)
            .enableAutoManage(activity /* FragmentActivity */, new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
                    ToastUtils.show(activity, R.string.login_failed);
                }
            })
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, mGso)
            .build();

    callback.registerCallback(listener);
    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGac);
    activity.startActivityForResult(signInIntent, REQUEST_GOOGLE_SIGNIN);

    // disconnect the client
    mGac.stopAutoManage(activity);
    mGac.disconnect();

}
```

or
 as your log mention:

```
 You have wrong OAuth2 related configurations, please check. Detailed error: UNREGISTERED_ON_API_CONSOLE
```

---

```
So, Problem can be:
    1. Sh1 key add in your api
    2. Api key type like for android or web
    3. Check Internet Connection
```

Sorry, for my english.
I hope this will help you. thanks

Comment: I also found a strange thing. If I install the apk which is built locally, this error  never happened.If I download from google play store, this error ocurred.But there is no difference between these two apks because I deliver google store with the local one.

Comment: You were right, my SHA1 key got wrong by some reason.[here is the reason](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40988326/7244483)

Answer (score 0):

Try the solution in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33846801/error-12501-authenticating-with-google-sign-in), by changing your code and using this code

```
mGso = newGoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
.requestIdToken(AuthenticatedActivity.this.getResources()
.getString(R.string.server_client_id))
.requestEmail()
.build();
```

For more information, check this another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34600278/status-code-12501-authenticating-with-google-sign-in) if it can help you.

Comment: I read the so question and not the same reason exactly. but thanks any way.