# Google Play Games Service - Login Failed (OAUTH2: UNREGISTERED_ON_API_CONSOLE)

Tags: android, google-api, oauth-2.0, sha1, google-play-games

At the moment I'm trying to implement Google Play Games Services Sign In to my android app. I already had a lot of trouble so far, but it seems I', coming closer to it actually working.

**The Problem:**
When i press login, the sign-in function returns the following error:

```
02-18 12:31:51.122 5524-21263/? W/Auth: [GetToken] GetToken failed with status code: UNREGISTERED_ON_API_CONSOLE
02-18 12:31:51.128 5206-5723/? E/TokenRequestor: You have wrong OAuth2 related configurations, please check. Detailed error: UNREGISTERED_ON_API_CONSOLE
02-18 12:31:51.144 5206-32272/? W/GamesServiceBroker: Client connected with SDK 8487000, Services 10298230, and Games 39080030
```

**What I've done so far:**

I tried to follow the documentation as good as possible, but either I'm doing something wrong or it is kind of a mess. I guess somewhere, i made a mistake.

**My Manifest file includes this:**

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
            android:value="@string/app_id" />
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
```

I have a games-ids.xml file including the App-ID and ID's for highscores and achievements.

**My gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.duke.privatpc.quiztest"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':BaseGameUtils')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
}
```

This includes the BaseGameUtils downloaded from the Getting Started Page.

I set up the Game at the Google Play Developer Console and added the created App-ID.

I always used my own keystore for creating the apk and also for creating the App-ID. Is there any need to use the debug.keystore at any point?

As you can see here, the SHA1 are identical and the correct APP-ID is shown.

1. [APK SHA1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDxY1.png)
2. [Developer Console SHA1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bF0sa.png)

I honestly have no idea what I'm doing wrong. I also activated testing and entered my email adress.

Also, absolutely nothing happens when clicking my sign-in button. There is no Google Overlay popping up, I'm not sure if this is already weird?

I hope someone can help me, as I didn't find any questions that could help me and it's getting a bit frustrating for an amateur-programmer like me.

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to follow the steps in a related SO [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41012703/5995040). Kindly check if you have properly set the setting as suggested in the related post. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Where did you create the `OAuth 2.0` client for your app? From your screenshot it seems that this is the entry in the `Google API console`.

Did you also create an entry in the Game services section in the `Google Play Developer console` (see step 2 in the [Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling))? I had big problems with my current game, because I created the `OAuth 2.0` client manually in the `Google API console` and not in the `Google Play Developer console` and the `OAuth 2.0` IDs in both consoles didn't match. According to a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nkJS_W-VC9I&feature=youtu.be&t=3m34s) from `Google Developers` `OAuth 2.0` clients should only be created in the `Google Play Developer console`. I wrote more about what I did wrong in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43371321/7829433).