# Achievements not showing in Google Play Games

Tags: android, google-play-games, beta, achievements

I'm working on a Unity game and am using the Google Play Games Services, specifically the Leaderboards and the Achievements.
I'm using the play-games-plugin-for-unity: https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity

Currently my game is published as beta test.

While the achievements do seem to work, as in, they can be unlocked, and the popup appears correctly and I can see my progress from within the game. 
But I don't receive and experience points for them.
And when I look at my game in the Play Games App, there's no info about any achievements, as if there are none.

So it's basically the same problem as this: [Achievements not showing in Google Play Games App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43298677/achievements-not-showing-in-google-play-games-app)
Except in his case he had a OAuth2 Client IDs mismatch, but mine seem to be correct.

I was wondering if it's maybe just because my game hasn't been made public yet? (as it's still in Beta)
Edit: I've released it publicly now, and the achievements are still not showing, so that's definately not the cause.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Check the available [documentation for Achievements](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/achievements). Make sure that the game have at [least 5 achievements](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/achievements#minimum_achievements) before publishing. You can also check this tips(https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en) from the Play Console Help about Alpha/Beta tests. Try to check [post from unity](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1413027/google-play-games-services-not-showing-achievement.html) as well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it got way more than 5 achievements, and I can unlock them, I can see them in the game and everything works correctly there, they just arent visible in the Google Play Games app.

Comment: Sorry to bring that up, but I'm facing the same issue... Did you find any solution?

Comment: If I remember correctly, I think it fixed itself after a couple of days. I didn't get any XP for the achievements I unlocked before they were visible though.