# How to specify API Key in this sample code?

Tags: android, google-oauth, api-key, developer-console

I'm totally new to using Google API keys with Android, and I found this [example](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2) because I'm interested in doing a very simple Google Tasks notification app. However, despite having fixed all the Gradle build problems, I can't get the app to work.

When I run it on Android 8.0.0, as soon as I choose a Google account, I get `UNREGISTERED_ON_API_CONSOLE`. From searching, I understand it means the APK must be signed and the OAuth 2.0 client ID must be obtained. I have managed to do all that following (more or less) [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41012703/1168342).

The trouble I have is with the (5-year-old) sample code at https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client-samples/tree/master/tasks-android-sample -- I can't see where to specify the Client ID from the Console. The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2#android) mentions the API key (albeit for quota limitations, not because of security), but **not where it is used**:

> You must also specify the API key from the [Google API Console](https://console.developers.google.com/). Otherwise, the token that the AccountManager gives you only provides you with anonymous quota, which is usually very low. By contrast, by specifying an API key you receive a higher free quota, and can optionally set up billing for usage above that.
>
> Example code snippet taken from [tasks-android-sample](https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client-samples/tree/master/tasks-android-sample):

```
com.google.api.services.tasks.Tasks service;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  credential =
      GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(this, Collections.singleton(TasksScopes.TASKS));
  SharedPreferences settings = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  credential.setSelectedAccountName(settings.getString(PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME, null));
  service =
      new com.google.api.services.tasks.Tasks.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential)
          .setApplicationName("Google-TasksAndroidSample/1.0").build();
}

private void chooseAccount() {
  startActivityForResult(credential.newChooseAccountIntent(), REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  switch (requestCode) {
    case REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES:
      if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        haveGooglePlayServices();
      } else {
        checkGooglePlayServicesAvailable();
      }
      break;
    case REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION:
      if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        AsyncLoadTasks.run(this);
      } else {
        chooseAccount();
      }
      break;
    case REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER:
      if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getExtras() != null) {
        String accountName = data.getExtras().getString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
        if (accountName != null) {
          credential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);
          SharedPreferences settings = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
          SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
          editor.putString(PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME, accountName);
          editor.commit();
          AsyncLoadTasks.run(this);
        }
      }
      break;
  }
}
```

Where do I put the API key information in the approach used here (`GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2`) to avoid the `UNREGISTERED_ON_API_CONSOLE` error?

Edit: Additional info on [this page](https://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/authenticate) seems to imply authentication is much more complicated than the sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found a one-line fix, but it's far from obvious in the Google documentation I quoted above.

Inside the file [`AsyncLoadTasks.java`](https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client-samples/blob/master/tasks-android-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/tasks/android/AsyncLoadTasks.java) there's a line to fetch the tasks:

```
List<Task> tasks =
    client.tasks().list("@default").setFields("items/title").execute().getItems();
```

The OAuth 2.0 client ID can be added with the [`setKey`](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/tasks/v1/java/latest/com/google/api/services/tasks/Tasks.TasksOperations.List.html#setKey-java.lang.String-) method.

```
List<Task> tasks =
    client.tasks().list("@default").setFields("items/title")
            .setKey("Client_ID_from_API_Console")             // Added this call
            .execute().getItems();
```

To clarify what to use from the API Console, it looks like this (after you've [set it up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40997205/unregistered-on-api-console-while-getting-oauth2-token-on-android/41012703#41012703)):

[image]