# Android Firebase Authentication for Google Signin fails

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I followed the [firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin) from top to bottom and implemented a simple google Sign in option to my app. However, when I try to signin, the process halts after selecting a google account and results in an error inside the onActivityResult method:

```
if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
       GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
       if (result.isSuccess()) {
            // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
            GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
       } else {
            //THE CODE BREAKS HERE
            // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
       }
}
```

The code breaks at the `if (result.isSuccess())` condition. To elaborate further, here's the complete code I implemented after going through the doc:

**onCreate:**

```
public class TestLogin extends AppCompatActivity {

    private SignInButton mGoogleBtn;
    private static int RC_SIGN_IN = 226;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private  String TAG = "Checkmate";
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_login);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null){
                    //success
                }
            }
        };

        mGoogleBtn = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.googleBtn);

        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken("MY_CLIENT_ID-MY_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com")
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .enableAutoManage(this, new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
                        //Failed
                    }
                })
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();

        mGoogleBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                statusMessage.setText("Loading..");
                signIn();
            }
        });
    }
```

**signIn method:**

The SignIn method gets called when the **Google Signin button is clicked**:

```
    private void signIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }
```

**onActivityResult:**

onActivityResult is called when the result is received after clicking the button. This is where the error occurs:

```
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            if (result.isSuccess()) {
                // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
                GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
            } else {
                //THE CODE BREAKS HERE
                // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
            }
        }
    }
```

**Handling Firebase Login code for Google:**

This method **never gets called** because the code breaks at the onActivityResult condition.

```
    private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(final GoogleSignInAccount acct) {

        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        
                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                        // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                        // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Toast.makeText(TestLogin.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }
```

**Checklist**:

> Yes, I added the google_services.json file to the /app directory
>
> Yes, I created a new OAuth Client Key in the Google Credentials page

**Here's my gradle:**

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.6.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**And..**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried accessing the GoogleSignInResult object to see if there's any indication there of what went wrong? e.g. result.getStatus().getStatusMessage();

Comment: I logged with `result.getStatus()` and it returned the message: `Status{statusCode=unknown status code:12501, resolution=null}` @IvanWooll

Comment: I didn't log with `result.getStatus().getStatusMessage();` though

Comment: The answers at this related question suggest that there is something wrong with your client ID, package name, or SHA1 key.  Confirm that all of them are correct: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33846801/4815718

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my previous test app using Firebase FriendlyChat, I have encountered similar failure in Sign In, but I have solved it by going Google API console (https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=) then download "client_secret.json" (in my case, I need to rename the downloaded filename "client_secret_xxxxx.json") for your Android client, put this file in your AndroidStudio project under "/src/main/resources" (create "resources" folder if not exist) then try to compile and run your Android app again.

Summary: you need 2 json files : "google-services.json" from Firebase Console and "client_secret.json" from Google API Console.

Hope this solve your problem.

Comment: dont forget to add your certificate SHA1 fingerprint in Firebase Console.

Comment: Authentication failed again!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have entered the SHA1 of your signing keystore.
Here's the guide https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth

You have to find two directories,
1. a directory where JDK have been installed
2. .android

If you are using Windows, '.android' folder might be placed in 'C:\Users\username\', and JDK directory might be placed in like 'C:\Users\Program files\java\'.

In my case, my OS is Windows, so first i was looking for my jdk folder.

In 'jdk_folder\bin\' you would find 'keytool.exe' and I used this command

'.\keytool -exportcert -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Users\sgc109\
.android\debug.keystore'.

Then, copy SHA1 key and paste to firebase console(setting - general - my app - SHA certificate finger print(?)' (I live in Korea, so names of menu could be different with me) and it works :)

Answer (score 0):

check if "Identity Toolkit API" is enabled in  [google API console](https://console.developers.google.com)

Answer (score 0):

Go to the firebase console and enable the sign in provider first.
https://console.firebase.google.com/u/2/project/ipay-71f01/authentication/providers

I had the same issue but this was the solution for me. 
Thanks