# Firebase sign in anonymous authentication failed

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using Anonymous method to login. When i install the application through USB, it working fine i.e user successfully signed in using sign in Anonymous method, but when i generate signed apk and then test it, authentication get failed with giving an Exception:

**The Android package name and signing-certificate fingerprint, package_name and fingerprint, do not match the app restrictions configured on your API key. Please use the API Console to update your key restrictions.**

I try to store client_secret.json as suggested in the answer [Android Firebase Authentication for Google Signin fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39900425/android-firebase-authentication-for-google-signin-fails)
But it doesn't worked.
I have enabled SignIn Method in firebase authentication.

And i keep the security as true for now.

Please help me out.

Comment: check on firebase, Anonymous Authentication is enabled ?

Comment: @ZaidMirza yes, anonymous authentication is enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because you need to generate a SHA1 Key for production and paste it into your firebase console

you can refer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39144629/how-to-add-sha-1-to-android-application) to see how to do it

Comment: i just checked in project setting, its already there. And i am using firebase realtime database since June, it work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate SHA1 key for release apk. Debug apk and release apk have different SHA1 key.

Comment: Is there any way to check the sha1 key for debug and relaese apk.?

Comment: @Vinay yes, go to your right top corner you will see a tag that says gradle, press there, press app - Tasks - android - press signinReport .... thats all and if you cant see the report you need to toogle textview at the left corner of your log

Comment: for the release sha1 just follow the link i provided