# Android Google SignIn

Tags: android, google-signin, oauth-2.0

I created a project and a Android credentials in 
https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=XXXXX

I'm following this steps to add Google SignIn on my Android app:
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating#prerequisites

My first doubt is. How I can get the google-services.json file after credential is created on google console? I'm only able to download a client_secret_XXXXXXXXXXX-asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf.apps.googleusercontent.com.json

After everything setup following the Google SignIn guide I can't get the token from Google API. 
I found this question: [New Google sign in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33583326/new-google-sign-in-android)

> The first step tells you to create the configuration file (which
>   creates an OAuth 2.0 client ID for you and inserts it into the
>   google-services.json)
>
> Then later, it says again about creating a OAuth 2.0 client ID, but
>   this time it says that you have to do it for Web application
>
> And this is the confusing part! (at least for me) because i was just
>   taking the client id created for the android OAuth and not creating a
>   new one for Web application (I thought the documentation was just
>   redundant or something)
>
> As it says, it is this one, and only this one the one you have to use
>   as a parameter of the methods requestIdToken or requestServerAuthCode.
>
> Forget about using the Android OAuth ID in this methods because then
>   you will get all the time the ugly status code response 12501.
>
> I think the main problem is that the documentation is a bit confusing
>   about this. Or maybe because it is a bit strange the fact that you
>   have to create two OAuth IDs.
>
> So as a summary, you need TWO OAuth IDs, one for android and one for
>   web application, and you have to set each one in the correct place.

There says that I have to create a web application credential. 
Now I'm confused, I have 2 json files (client_secret_XXXXXXXXXXX-asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf.apps.googleusercontent.com.json and google-services.json, and 2 Client ID (Android and Web)

```
    // Configure sign-in to request the user's ID, email address, and basic
    // profile. ID and basic profile are included in DEFAULT_SIGN_IN.
    String serverClientId = getString(R.string.oauth_client_google);
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .requestIdToken(serverClientId)
            .requestProfile()
            .build();
    // Build a GoogleApiClient with access to the Google Sign-In API and the
    // options specified by gso.
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();
```

**R.string.oauth_client_google is the Web Application Client ID. If I set the Android Client ID there is not working.**

Do I really need a Android Client ID?

Anyone knows the right steps to do to have: first the google account selector and then the token from google?

Comment: Is this helpful? http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/03/registering-oauth-clients-for-google.html

Comment: Thanks @steven following the link I could get the google-services.json again.
But I still have the issue when I try to get the tokenId adding .requestIdToken(serverClientId) on GoogleSignInOptions. I have to use the Web Application Client ID to make it works instead of the Android Client ID 
That is very confuse..

Answer (score 0):

Go to https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start to configure and get google_services.json by following the steps.Everything is written over there clearly. client secret is not required. Keep that google_services.json file in your app folder.

And then in your activity declare

```
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
```

After that in onCreate method write

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
              .requestEmail()
              .build();

      mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
              .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
              .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
              .addApi(Plus.API)
              .build();
```

And proceed further following google document https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in#add_the_google_sign-in_button_to_your_app

Comment: I don't need Plus.API 
If I add requestIdToken(serverClientId) with the Android Client ID is not working INVALID_AUDIENCE, but it is working if I use the Web application Client ID.
That is what I don't understand, the diference between Web Application and Android Client ID and why I created a Android application but I have to use Web Application to make it work

Comment: Plus.API will be deprecated soon