# ClassNotFoundException for SignInConfiguration when signing in with Google

Tags: android, google-play-services

I'm implementing Google login to an app. The login itself seems to work okay, but the moment I request either the user's e-mail or ID token I see the following stack trace in the log and the status from `GoogleSignInResult` as `Status{statusCode=unknown status code: 12500, resolution=null}`

```
03-30 13:59:09.821 3634-4322/? E/Parcel: Class not found when unmarshalling: com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInConfiguration
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInConfiguration
     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:309)
     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:273)
     at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2281)
     at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2245)
     at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2152)
     at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2485)
     at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:221)
     at android.os.BaseBundle.getString(BaseBundle.java:918)
     at android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(Intent.java:5767)
     at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:2365)
     at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1848)
     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityAsUser(ActivityManagerService.java:5809)
     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivity(ActivityManagerService.java:5593)
     at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:142)
     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:3786)
     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:461)
  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInConfiguration" on path: DexPathList[[directory "."],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:309) 
     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:273) 
     at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2281) 
     at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2245) 
     at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2152) 
     at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2485) 
     at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:221) 
     at android.os.BaseBundle.getString(BaseBundle.java:918) 
     at android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(Intent.java:5767) 
     at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:2365) 
     at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1848) 
     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityAsUser(ActivityManagerService.java:5809) 
     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivity(ActivityManagerService.java:5593) 
     at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:142) 
     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:3786) 
     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:461) 
    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInConfiguration
     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
     at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
     at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
            ... 18 more
  Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

This is the code I'm using for trying to log in the user:

```
public class SignInActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private final static String TAG = SignInActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    protected final static int REQUEST_CODE_GOOGLE_LOGIN = 1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in);

        GoogleSignInOptions googleSignInOptions = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
//                .requestEmail() // Causes ClassNotFoundException for SignInConfiguration
//                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.google_server_client_id)) // Causes ClassNotFoundException for SignInConfiguration
                .build();
        final GoogleApiClient googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this, this)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, googleSignInOptions)
                .build();

        SignInButton signInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.signInButton);
        signInButton.setScopes(googleSignInOptions.getScopeArray());
        signInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(googleApiClient);
                startActivityForResult(signInIntent, REQUEST_CODE_GOOGLE_LOGIN);
            }
        });

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_GOOGLE_LOGIN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            handleGoogleSignInResult(result);
        }
    }

    protected void handleGoogleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult googleSignInResult) {
        Logging.debug(TAG, "handleGoogleSignInResult(" + googleSignInResult + ")");
        if (googleSignInResult.isSuccess()) {
            GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = googleSignInResult.getSignInAccount();
            final String idToken = googleSignInAccount.getIdToken();
            if (idToken != null) {
                Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this, "Successfully logged in.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // Do fun stuff here
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "ID token was null. Unable to sign in user.");
            }
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to sign in with Google. Status:" + googleSignInResult.getStatus());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onConnectionFailed(" + connectionResult + ")");
    }
    
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

I'm using the following gradle dependency:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.4.0'
```

The logged exception seems to come from another process. I've even tried to instanciate `com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInConfiguration` my Activity to be sure that I have the class accessible.

This is happening on the debug build which doesn't use proguard.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33583326/new-google-sign-in-android

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think this might be a red-herring.  I had the exact same stack trace and have spent a ton of time trying to determine the cause.  I came across a similar post while researching which indicated it might be a Samsung only exception that could be ignore (them inspecting intents in transit or something).  Sure enough, I tried on an HTCOne device and the exception no longer appeared.  I still had the same overall Google Auth problems, but at least I could move on to the real issue which (for me at least) appears to be SHA/Cert/Account/Signing related.  Anyway - hope this helps (something to check on anyway)

Comment: Yep, it seems like you're right. This was indeed on a Samsung device, and I was using an incorrect server client ID. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 9):

I solved my problem by putting ["App signing Key"](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html) to OAuth 2.0 Client ID SHA-1 finger print **instead of signed key which was generated by using keytool**. If you have checked "Google Play App Signing" in Google Play Console, the usual signed key will not work. Check out your App signing Key in Google Play Console>App signing>App signing certificate and then copy SHA-1 certificate fingerprint and paste to Google API console OAuth 2.0 Client ID. It worked for me!

Comment: I have same problem i enable Google play App sign, without give my own keystore(jks) now i got this issue in Released app in playstore. I have the SHA-1 key now what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue fixed in this way: I deleted my project the google developer console, and created another one with a **different name**, also I changed my package name almost completely: for example from com.example.android.appname to com.y.android.anothername. Then I generated signed apk with my previous certificate and google signing worked without giving me that error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and i found that i was using wrong default_web_client_id in **requestIdToken()** during Google sign in.

Solution:

1. Open https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials page
2. Copy **Web client** (auto created by Google Service) from **OAuth 2.0 Client IDs**
3. Paste this key in requestIdToken() of your GoogleSignInOptions.Builder