# Google Sign in not working

Tags: android, android-intent, google-signin

I am following [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in) for Google Sign. Having a weird problem when I call

```
Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent (mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult (signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
```

Its seems Intent has been fired but **I can't see account picker dialog**. I am using

`compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.6.1"`

When I check does googleclient object is connected, it returns true.

> **It's working in some of the devices, but not on every device(specially xiaomi)**

Implementation

```
@OnClick (R.id.google_singin_button)
void signInButtonClicked () {

    HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<> ();
    map.put (AllAnalytics.LABEL, AllAnalytics.Label.SIGN_IN_GOOGLE);
    map.put (AllAnalytics.ACTION, AllAnalytics.Action.CLICK);
    map.put (AllAnalytics.CATEGORY, AllAnalytics.Category.REGISTRATION_SCREEN);

    aa.analyticsEventOccur (map);

    if (null != mGoogleApiClient) {
       // Log.e(TAG,mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()+"");
        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent (mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult (signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult (requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED != resultCode)
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent (data);
        handleSignInResult (result);
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
    mActivity = (RegisterActivity) getActivity ();
    GoogleSignInOptions gso
            = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder (GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestServerAuthCode (getString (R.string.google_client_auth), false)
            .requestEmail ()
            .build ();

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder (getContext ())
            .enableAutoManage (mActivity , this)
            .addApi (Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build ();

}
```

Log Cat

```
Class not found when unmarshalling: com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInConfiguration
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInConfiguration
   at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
   at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:309)
   at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:273)
   at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2281)
   at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2245)
   at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2152)
   at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2485)
   at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:221)
   at android.os.BaseBundle.containsKey(BaseBundle.java:269)
   at android.content.Intent.hasExtra(Intent.java:4884)
   at com.miui.server.XSpaceManagerService.isPublicIntent(XSpaceManagerService.java:174)
   at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisorInjector.checkXSpaceControl(ActivityStackSupervisorInjector.java:56)
   at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:897)
   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityAsUser(ActivityManagerService.java:3478)
   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivity(ActivityManagerService.java:3465)
   at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:140)
   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2245)
   at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInConfiguration" on path: DexPathList[[directory "."],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
   at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
   at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
   at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:309) 
   at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:273) 
   at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2281) 
   at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2245) 
   at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2152) 
   at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2485) 
   at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:221) 
   at android.os.BaseBundle.containsKey(BaseBundle.java:269) 
   at android.content.Intent.hasExtra(Intent.java:4884) 
   at com.miui.server.XSpaceManagerService.isPublicIntent(XSpaceManagerService.java:174) 
   at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisorInjector.checkXSpaceControl(ActivityStackSupervisorInjector.java:56) 
   at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:897) 
   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityAsUser(ActivityManagerService.java:3478) 
   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivity(ActivityManagerService.java:3465) 
   at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:140) 
   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2245) 
   at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446) 
    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInConfiguration
   at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
   at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
   at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available

10-11 23:46:17.873 1387-4537/? E/JavaBinder: *** Uncaught remote exception!  (Exceptions are not yet supported across processes.)
java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel@33c1f490: Unmarshalling unknown type code 6684783 at offset 320
   at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2228)
   at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2485)
   at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:221)
   at android.os.BaseBundle.containsKey(BaseBundle.java:269)
   at android.content.Intent.hasExtra(Intent.java:4884)
   at com.miui.server.XSpaceManagerService.shouldResolveAgain(XSpaceManagerService.java:145)
   at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisorInjector.resolveXSpaceIntent(ActivityStackSupervisorInjector.java:68)
   at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:898)
   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityAsUser(ActivityManagerService.java:3478)
   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivity(ActivityManagerService.java:3465)
   at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:140)
   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2245)
   at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)


10-11 23:46:17.873 1387-4537/? A/ActivityManager: Activity Manager Crash
java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel@33c1f490: Unmarshalling unknown type code 6684783 at offset 320
    at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2228)
    at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2485)
    at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:221)
    at android.os.BaseBundle.containsKey(BaseBundle.java:269)
    at android.content.Intent.hasExtra(Intent.java:4884)
    at com.miui.server.XSpaceManagerService.shouldResolveAgain(XSpaceManagerService.java:145)
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisorInjector.resolveXSpaceIntent(ActivityStackSupervisorInjector.java:68)
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:898)
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityAsUser(ActivityManagerService.java:3478)
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivity(ActivityManagerService.java:3465)
    at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:140)
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2245)
            at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)
```

Comment: i used the same version auth9.6.1 recently its working fine. go through google signin documentation one more time.

Comment: @HourGlass have been there many times.

Comment: can u share the whole implementation part ?

Comment: @HourGlass updated

Comment: new GoogleApiClient.Builder (getContext ()) , please add connectionFailureListener to enableAutomanage(mactivity, errorlistener) and check what error you are getting. if its developer error, you haven't configured package name and SHA1 key with google or improper

Comment: @HourGlass not getting any error :/. It shows its connected.

Comment: .requestServerAuthCode (getString (R.string.google_client_auth), false) try without this line

Comment: @HourGlass same behaviour

Comment: no idea. y you are facing this weird problem.

Comment: I am getting the same problem but only with MI 4i phone while using Places API to start activity for picking up place. Did you solve this problem? If yes, please help me solve this.

Comment: Updating your Google play services to 10.0.1 might help .. com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.0.1

Comment: In the document, they say that it's require services version 9.8.0 and run on device OS > 2.3 ( AVD with GG API >4.2.2), pls check those config first.

Comment: **Check this answers ** - http://stackoverflow.com/a/33689161 - http://stackoverflow.com/a/36506572

Comment: Please update to the latest version: 10.0.1 https://firebase.google.com/support/releases

Comment: is your onactivity result() called?

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 No

Answer (score 1):

Just check your `onActivityResult()` is called or not because you have used `Fragment`. So you have to pass the `Activity` result from activity to fragment.

In your `RegisterActivity` you have to write this

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
    fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

and then you will receive result in your `Fragment`.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Its is already working in most of the devices, but not on every devices. Above trick doesn't helped me. :(

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried disabling ProGuard? Set minifyEnabled to false in your build.gradle and see if it helps, your configuration may be out of date or incorrect.

Also you can check if your device is runing 9.6.1+ version of Google Play services.

Comment: tried disabling Proguard. google version to 9.8.0. On Activity result not called, app freezes.