# Samsung mobile Google login encountered a very strange problem. Other types of mobile phones did not have this problem

Tags: android, google-signin

```
2019-12-10 15:35:54.982 3881-12824/? I/WindowManager: commitFinishDrawingLocked: mDrawState=READY_TO_SHOW Surface(name=StatusBar[12522])/@0xb43d8ce
2019-12-10 15:35:54.984 31345-31345/? W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@2db7c8c
2019-12-10 15:35:54.990 3881-12824/? E/Parcel: Class not found when unmarshalling: com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInConfiguration
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInConfiguration
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:453)
        at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2827)
        at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2781)
        at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2684)
        at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:3053)
        at android.os.BaseBundle.initializeFromParcelLocked(BaseBundle.java:288)
        at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:232)
        at android.os.BaseBundle.getString(BaseBundle.java:1155)
        at android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(Intent.java:8111)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityStarter.startActivity(ActivityStarter.java:730)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityStarter.startActivity(ActivityStarter.java:668)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityStarter.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStarter.java:1534)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityStarter.execute(ActivityStarter.java:610)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityAsUser(ActivityManagerService.java:6642)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityAsUser(ActivityManagerService.java:6533)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivity(ActivityManagerService.java:6524)
        at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact$startActivity$(IActivityManager.java:10833)
        at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact(IActivityManager.java:111)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:4136)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:739)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInConfiguration
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:1346)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:1406)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:453) 
        at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2827) 
        at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2781) 
        at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2684) 
        at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:3053) 
        at android.os.BaseBundle.initializeFromParcelLocked(BaseBundle.java:288) 
        at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:232) 
        at android.os.BaseBundle.getString(BaseBundle.java:1155) 
        at android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(Intent.java:8111) 
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityStarter.startActivity(ActivityStarter.java:730) 
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityStarter.startActivity(ActivityStarter.java:668) 
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityStarter.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStarter.java:1534) 
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityStarter.execute(ActivityStarter.java:610) 
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityAsUser(ActivityManagerService.java:6642) 
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityAsUser(ActivityManagerService.java:6533) 
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivity(ActivityManagerService.java:6524) 
        at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact$startActivity$(IActivityManager.java:10833) 
        at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact(IActivityManager.java:111) 
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:4136) 
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:739) 
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
2019-12-10 15:35:54.991 3881-12824/? W/Bundle: Failed to parse Bundle, but defusing quietly
    android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInConfiguration
        at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2855)
        at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2781)
        at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2684)
        at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:3053)
        at android.os.BaseBundle.initializeFromParcelLocked(BaseBundle.java:288)
        at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:232)
        at android.os.BaseBundle.getString(BaseBundle.java:1155)
        at android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(Intent.java:8111)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityStarter.startActivity(ActivityStarter.java:730)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityStarter.startActivity(ActivityStarter.java:668)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityStarter.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStarter.java:1534)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityStarter.execute(ActivityStarter.java:610)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityAsUser(ActivityManagerService.java:6642)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityAsUser(ActivityManagerService.java:6533)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivity(ActivityManagerService.java:6524)
        at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact$startActivity$(IActivityManager.java:10833)
        at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact(IActivityManager.java:111)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:4136)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:739)
2019-12-10 15:35:54.991 3881-12824/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=com.google.android.gms.auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN typ=null flg=0x0 cmp=ComponentInfo{com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.ui.SignInActivity}} from uid 10245
2019-12-10 15:35:54.996 3881-12824/? D/CustomFrequencyManagerService: acquireDVFSLockLocked : type : DVFS_MIN_LIMIT  frequency : 2314000  uid : 1000  pid : 3881  pkgName : AMS_APP_SWITCH@CPU_MIN@54
2019-12-10 15:35:54.997 3881-12824/? D/ActivityManagerPerformance: AMP_acquire() APP_SWITCH
```

It's only Samsung's phones that have this problem. Samsung S8, S8 +, S10

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36309169/classnotfoundexception-for-signinconfiguration-when-signing-in-with-google and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33583326/new-google-sign-in-android

Answer (score -1):

The error log says that there was a problem parsing the Bundle object. Have you looked at the code.

```
at com.android.server.am.ActivityStarter.startActivity(ActivityStarter.java:730)
```

Click the ActivityStarter.java:730 bit...it should direct you to where the problem originates from. Then you can be able to follow through and check what the problem may be.

Hope that helps.