# Firebase login with Google fails after I generated signed APK

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-play, google-authentication

It's the first time that I try to release an app on Google Play Store. I used authentification with Google account from Firebase and it worked before, but now if I try to run the app I get an error when I try to sign in.
I added the keys that I generate from the Google Play Console to the Firebase Console but I still get this error:

````
2020-04-25 14:59:10.863 3668-4853/? E/Parcel: Class not found when unmarshalling: com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInConfiguration
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInConfiguration
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:453)
        at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2843)
        at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2797)
        at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2700)
        at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:3067)
        at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:257)
        at android.os.BaseBundle.getString(BaseBundle.java:1086)
        at android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(Intent.java:7706)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityStarter.startActivity(ActivityStarter.java:468)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityStarter.startActivityLocked(ActivityStarter.java:419)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityStarter.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStarter.java:1308)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityAsUser(ActivityManagerService.java:6035)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivity(ActivityManagerService.java:5887)
        at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact(IActivityManager.java:121)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:3863)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:682)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInConfiguration
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:1355)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:1415)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:453) 
        at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2843) 
        at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2797) 
        at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2700) 
        at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:3067) 
        at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:257) 
        at android.os.BaseBundle.getString(BaseBundle.java:1086) 
        at android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(Intent.java:7706) 
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityStarter.startActivity(ActivityStarter.java:468) 
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityStarter.startActivityLocked(ActivityStarter.java:419) 
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityStarter.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStarter.java:1308) 
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityAsUser(ActivityManagerService.java:6035) 
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivity(ActivityManagerService.java:5887) 
        at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact(IActivityManager.java:121) 
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:3863) 
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:682) 
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
2020-04-25 14:59:11.071 3668-8343/? E/Parcel: Class not found when unmarshalling: com.google.android.gms.common.api.Scope
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.common.api.Scope
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:453)
        at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2843)
        at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2797)
        at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableArray(Parcel.java:2905)
        at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2754)
        at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:3067)
        at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:257)
        at android.os.BaseBundle.getString(BaseBundle.java:1086)
        at android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(Intent.java:7706)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityStarter.startActivity(ActivityStarter.java:468)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityStarter.startActivityLocked(ActivityStarter.java:419)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityStarter.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStarter.java:1308)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityInPackage(ActivityManagerService.java:6592)
        at com.android.server.am.PendingIntentRecord.sendInner(PendingIntentRecord.java:393)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityIntentSender(ActivityManagerService.java:6309)
        at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact(IActivityManager.java:1635)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:3863)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:682)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.common.api.Scope
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:1355)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:1415)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:453) 
        at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2843) 
        at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2797) 
        at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableArray(Parcel.java:2905) 
        at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2754) 
        at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:3067) 
        at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:257) 
        at android.os.BaseBundle.getString(BaseBundle.java:1086) 
        at android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(Intent.java:7706) 
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityStarter.startActivity(ActivityStarter.java:468) 
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityStarter.startActivityLocked(ActivityStarter.java:419) 
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityStarter.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStarter.java:1308) 
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityInPackage(ActivityManagerService.java:6592) 
        at com.android.server.am.PendingIntentRecord.sendInner(PendingIntentRecord.java:393) 
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityIntentSender(ActivityManagerService.java:6309) 
        at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact(IActivityManager.java:1635) 
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:3863) 
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:682) 
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
2020-04-25 14:59:11.186 4564-4787/? E/cipr: *~*~*~ Channel {0} was not shutdown properly!!! ~*~*~*
        Make sure to call shutdown()/shutdownNow() and wait until awaitTermination() returns true.
    java.lang.RuntimeException: ManagedChannel allocation site
        at cipq.<init>(:com.google.android.gms@201216021@20.12.16 (040408-306753009):2)
        at cipr.<init>(:com.google.android.gms@201216021@20.12.16 (040408-306753009):2)
        at cijj.b(:com.google.android.gms@201216021@20.12.16 (040408-306753009):21)
        at tdt.a(:com.google.android.gms@201216021@20.12.16 (040408-306753009):24)
        at tdt.a(:com.google.android.gms@201216021@20.12.16 (040408-306753009):52)
        at ardz.call(:com.google.android.gms@201216021@20.12.16 (040408-306753009):27)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at tkq.b(:com.google.android.gms@201216021@20.12.16 (040408-306753009):12)
        at tkq.run(:com.google.android.gms@201216021@20.12.16 (040408-306753009):7)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at tqq.run(:com.google.android.gms@201216021@20.12.16 (040408-306753009):0)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) ```
````

Comment: check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36309169/classnotfoundexception-for-signinconfiguration-when-signing-in-with-google

Comment: I already looked at the answers, but it's not helping.

Comment: please share the code to better understand the problem.