# Using google-services.json file in NaticeScript 2

Tags: android, google-signin, google-oauth, nativescript

I am developing an app in **NativeScript 2.0** that authenticates an user by [Google's Sign-In](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in?configured=true).

I also have a backend that checks the logged in user. For this **I need an access token** to access email and some profile data like display name and photo (via `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json&access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN_FROM_APP>`).

My **Android implementation** looks like this:

```
var app = require("application");
var context = app.android.context;

var options = new com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
    .requestEmail()
    .requestProfile()

     // get access token
    .requestServerAuthCode('MY_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com', false)

    .build();
```

In my **activity result** the [GoogleSignInResult](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInResult) tells me that the operation was NOT successful (**status code 12501**):

```
activity.onActivityResult = function(requestCode, resultCode, data) {
    var signInResult = com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
    if (!signInResult.isSuccess()) {
        // code goes here

        // 12501
        var statusCode = signInResult.getStatus().getStatusCode();
    }
}
```

As I learned from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33583326/new-google-sign-in-android) I have to create a special client ID / API key for my app and have to include the `google-services.json` into a sub folder of my Android Studio project.

**In debug environment** I used the **SHA-1 key** from by `debug.keystore` file of my home folder.

---

**My question:**

What is the right way to use the Google Sign-in in a NativeScript project?

Comment: How did you get this `com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions.Builder` to work? I keep getting `cannot find name com`