# Integrating Google Sign in button in Android App

Tags: android, android-activity, google-signin

Okay i was trying this code from Google https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in?configured=true

LoginActivity

```
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
GoogleSignInOptions gso;
SignInButton signIn_btn;
private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 0;
ProgressDialog progress_dialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    buidNewGoogleApiClient();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    customizeSignBtn();
    setBtnClickListeners();


    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(this.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Typeface myTypeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Big Daddy St.ttf");
    Typeface myTypeFaceFacebook = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Big Daddy St.ttf");


    mainImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    textView1.setOnClickListener(this);
    textView1.setTypeface(myTypeFace);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login_facebook);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
    button.setTypeface(myTypeFaceFacebook);



}

private void buidNewGoogleApiClient() {

    gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, this)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();
}

private void customizeSignBtn() {

    signIn_btn = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
    signIn_btn.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_STANDARD);
    signIn_btn.setScopes(gso.getScopeArray());

}

private void setBtnClickListeners() {
    // Button listeners
    signIn_btn.setOnClickListener(this);


}

protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {



        }
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        getSignInResult(result);
    }
}

private void getSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
GoogleSignInStatusCodes.getStatusCodeString(result.getStatus().getStatusCode());


    if (result.isSuccess()) {

        // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
        GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
        Toast.makeText(this, "email: " + acct.getEmail(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        //TextView user_name= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.userName);
        // TextView email_id= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.emailId);
        // user_name.setText("UserName: "+ acct.getDisplayName());
        // email_id.setText("Email Id: " + acct.getEmail());

        progress_dialog.dismiss();
    } else {
        // Signed out, show unauthenticated UI.
        try {


        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Exception: " +e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        //updateUI(false);
    }
}






@Override
public void onClick(View view) {




    if(view.getId() == R.id.textView1){
        Intent signupIntent = new Intent(this, SignUpScreen.class);
        startActivity(signupIntent);

    }

    if(view.getId() == R.id.btn_login_facebook){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, todelete.class);

        //Notification
        // notificationWithButton();
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    if(view.getId()==R.id.sign_in_button){
        Toast.makeText(this, "start sign process", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        gSignIn();


    }

}
private void gSignIn() {
    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
  //  progress_dialog.show();
}


void notificationWithButton(){
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        // Prepare intent which is triggered if the  notification button is pressed
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

        // Building the notifcation
        NotificationCompat.Builder nBuilder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher) // notification icon
                .setContentTitle("Button notification") // notification title
                .setContentText("Expand to show the buttons...") // content text
                .setTicker("Showing button notification") // status bar message
                .addAction(R.drawable.common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark, "Accept", pIntent) // accept notification button
                .addAction(R.drawable.common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal, "Cancel", pIntent); // cancel notification button

        mNotificationManager.notify(1001, nBuilder.build());

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "You need a higher version", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}


@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

}
```

Manifest.xml

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <!-- To access accounts configured on device -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <!-- To use account credentials -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WIFI" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"
```

/>

build.gradle (Project)

```
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

build.gradle (App)

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.1.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.6.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Your help will be much appreciated.

Edit: Added         GoogleSignInStatusCodes.getStatusCodeString(result.getStatus().getStatusCode());
 which returns 10, corresponding to DEVELOPER_ERROR.

I had previously created a key for Google Maps, which is included in my Project (In Manifest file, meta tags), now do I have to create another Key? If yes, how do I include it?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? What should be the steps your program takes?

Answer (score 0):

To debug this, I would do this: breakpoint / print to log what you get back from Google on success login. That will tell you where the data is what you want.

What is the next Activity? Looks like you are starting something from Google, but it would make more sense to start something of your own making.

*edit* went over it. Some thoughts:

```
googleSignInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(this);

// Can be done this way:
googleSignInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
googleSignInButton.setOnClickListener(this);
```

And this is how I have done something like it:

```
SignInButton buttonGoogle = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.button_google);
assert buttonGoogle != null;
buttonGoogle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }
});
```

And to handle a Successful login from Google you will need something like this:
*getResources().getString(R.string.google) => Getting a string from the strings.xml*

```
/**
 * Handling the result from Google.
 * @param result                    You know, tha package.
 */
private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
    Log.d("handleSignInResult:", "" + result.isSuccess());
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
        GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
        successfulLogin(getResources().getString(R.string.google),
                acct.getDisplayName(),
                acct.getId(),
                acct.getEmail());
    } else { // but is never used atm.
        String message = String.format(getResources().getString(R.string.communication_signed_out), getResources().getString(R.string.google));
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: I use oauth 2 to sign in Google by Webview. If you an example...I will post for you.

Comment: Thank you for that, but can you see what is wrong in the above code?

Comment: Added some code that might help. This works with me. Hope you understand how it works.

Comment: Let me try and get back, where are you starting a new activity on successful sign in?

Comment: if (result.isSuccess()) is what runs if you successfully log in. Use Toast of System.out.print("Succes"); to see if it gets there. If not, you will see a toast.

Comment: what is successfulLogin()?

Comment: Okay, made changes to the code as you suggested, result was the Toast string in 'communication_signed_out'.So did not login. Now I am uninstalling the app from device and running again...and still cannot login..Toast same as 'communication_signed_out'..see updated code

Comment: Log.d("handleSignInResult:", "" + result.isSuccess()) is false

Comment: That means your login failed: you did **not** login. Recommended: create a Google test account with a simple password so you know that the login went successful.

Comment: Why isn't my current google account working? It is valid.

Comment: I have no idea why that should not work. Makes no sense really. That's why it is an idea to check with an other account. The code that I gave you works in my app. Other than this, I have no idea why it does not work on your side.

Comment: Could there be something with json file? I pasted that file in app directory

Comment: Why do you need a JSON file?

Comment: Following this https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in?configured=true, adding google-services.json file.

Comment: Oh, yea, forgot about that one. Hard to tell if that is the problem from where I am. Not sure how to test that. I followed the same thing, so it should be the right way.

Comment: For some reason, I didn't go through this http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/03/registering-oauth-clients-for-google.html. Is this the reason?

Comment: Yea, you need that.

Comment: And? Don't leave us hanging ;)

Comment: When the tutorial says "Create a web client ID for your server", the id is there, and I have included that in my Project, but what do we mean by 'your server'? Is the link provided by Google? Sorry a little lost here

Comment: I previously created a key for Google Maps, now do I create a separate key for Google Sign in?

Comment: Yes, they are separate.

Comment: See my Manifest file...this way?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
           private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
                Log.d(String.valueOf(LoginActivity.this), "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
                if (result.isSuccess()) {
                    // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
                    GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
              if (acct != null) {

                        Intent iWelcomeActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, WelcomeActivity.class);
                        iWelcomeActivity.putExtra("USERNAME", acct.getDisplayName());
                        iWelcomeActivity.putExtra("EMAIL", acct.getEmail();
);
                        startActivity(iWelcomeActivity);
                    }
                } else {
                    // Signed out, show unauthenticated UI.
                    //updateUI(false);
                }
            }
```

When user taps sigin button an intent will prompts the user to select a Google account to sign in with.
 **onActivityResult** method, retrieve the sign-in result and `handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result)` is called .

If sign-in succeeded, you can call the `getSignInAccount method` to get a **GoogleSignInAccount object** that contains information about the signed-in user.
Use **GoogleSignInAccount object** to retrieve information as `acct.getDisplayName(),acct.getEmail()` and pass it to next activity as done in above code.

Hopes it will help

Comment: Tried your code, 11-06 19:36:33.118 468-468/com.example......LoginActivity@5956e2d: handleSignInResult:false

Comment: When debugging, in OnActivityResult,            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data); result has nothing

Comment: is data in OnActivityResult null??

Comment: Yes, nothing in data. Do you want me to post all the contents in data?As

Comment: data = {Intent@5130} "Intent { (has extras) }"
 mAction = null
 mCategories = null
 mClipData = null
 mComponent = null
 mContentUserHint = -2
 mData = null
 mExtras = {Bundle@5177} "Bundle[{googleSignInStatus=Status{statusCode=DEVELOPER_ERROR, resolution=null}}]"
 mFlags = 0
 mPackage = null
 mSelector = null
 mSourceBounds = null
 mType = null
 shadow$_klass_ = {Class@1392} "class android.content.Intent"
 shadow$_monitor_ = -2000768399

Comment: When I uninstall the app, and start again, it shows dialog with gmail accounts but does not start ActivityUserProfile. From then on, even the dialog doesnt open on clicking

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this same error, until I found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33583326/new-google-sign-in-android). The problem was that if you don't configure your debug build to use your release signing key, it will use a default debugkeystore instead. If you've set up the API Key correctly, they won't match. Obviously, it would work if you build a release .apk with your release signing key, but if you are debugging (in development) you may have overlooked this process.

### The Solution

1. **Goto** *Build* > *Edit Build Types...*
2. On the *Signing Tab*, **Create** a new entry for your release signing key alias and keystore. You can name it whatever you like, I used '*release*'.
3. Now, on the *Build Types Tab*, for the 'debug' build type, **Set** the *Signing Config* to whatever was created in step 2.
4. **Click** *OK*, and **Run** the app again.

Bob's your Auntie