# GoogleSignInResult always returning not success staus

Tags: java, android, google-signin, google-api-client

I have been following this tutorial to create a simple app with google sign in.

Tutorial link : http://www.androidhive.info/2014/02/android-login-with-google-plus-account-1/

I have followed the exact same steps mentioned in the tutorial. I have also generated the google-services.json file and placed it in the app folder.

When I click on the sign in button, accounts show up as shown in the below picture
[image]

When an account is chosen, the control reaches to

`public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)`

which contains

`GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);`

the result is always not success. Can anyone let me know the possible reason?
Here is my mainActivity.java file.

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DiskCacheStrategy;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.OptionalPendingResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        View.OnClickListener,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 007;

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    private SignInButton btnSignIn;
    private Button btnSignOut, btnRevokeAccess;
    private LinearLayout llProfileLayout;
    private ImageView imgProfilePic;
    private TextView txtName, txtEmail;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnSignIn = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_sign_in);
        btnSignOut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_sign_out);
        btnRevokeAccess = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_revoke_access);
        llProfileLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llProfile);
        imgProfilePic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgProfilePic);
        txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        txtEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);

        btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnSignOut.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnRevokeAccess.setOnClickListener(this);

        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this, this)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();

        // Customizing G+ button
        btnSignIn.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_STANDARD);
        btnSignIn.setScopes(gso.getScopeArray());
    }


    private void signIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }


    private void signOut() {
        Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
                new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(Status status) {
                        updateUI(false);
                    }
                });
    }

    private void revokeAccess() {
        Auth.GoogleSignInApi.revokeAccess(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
                new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(Status status) {
                        updateUI(false);
                    }
                });
    }

    private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
        Log.d(TAG, "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
            GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();

            Log.e(TAG, "display name: " + acct.getDisplayName());

            String personName = acct.getDisplayName();
            String personPhotoUrl = acct.getPhotoUrl().toString();
            String email = acct.getEmail();

            Log.e(TAG, "Name: " + personName + ", email: " + email
                    + ", Image: " + personPhotoUrl);

            txtName.setText(personName);
            txtEmail.setText(email);
            Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(personPhotoUrl)
                    .thumbnail(0.5f)
                    .crossFade()
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                    .into(imgProfilePic);

            updateUI(true);
        } else {
            // Signed out, show unauthenticated UI.
            updateUI(false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int id = v.getId();

        switch (id) {
            case R.id.btn_sign_in:
                signIn();
                break;

            case R.id.btn_sign_out:
                signOut();
                break;

            case R.id.btn_revoke_access:
                revokeAccess();
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            handleSignInResult(result);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        OptionalPendingResult<GoogleSignInResult> opr = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn(mGoogleApiClient);
        if (opr.isDone()) {
            // If the user's cached credentials are valid, the OptionalPendingResult will be "done"
            // and the GoogleSignInResult will be available instantly.
            Log.d(TAG, "Got cached sign-in");
            GoogleSignInResult result = opr.get();
            handleSignInResult(result);
        } else {
            // If the user has not previously signed in on this device or the sign-in has expired,
            // this asynchronous branch will attempt to sign in the user silently.  Cross-device
            // single sign-on will occur in this branch.
            showProgressDialog();
            opr.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<GoogleSignInResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(GoogleSignInResult googleSignInResult) {
                    hideProgressDialog();
                    handleSignInResult(googleSignInResult);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        // An unresolvable error has occurred and Google APIs (including Sign-In) will not
        // be available.
        Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed:" + connectionResult);
    }

    private void showProgressDialog() {
        if (mProgressDialog == null) {
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("loading");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        }

        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    private void hideProgressDialog() {
        if (mProgressDialog != null && mProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
            mProgressDialog.hide();
        }
    }

    private void updateUI(boolean isSignedIn) {
        if (isSignedIn) {
            btnSignIn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            btnSignOut.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            btnRevokeAccess.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            llProfileLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            btnSignIn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            btnSignOut.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            btnRevokeAccess.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            llProfileLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you share the status code?

Comment: @AshishRanjan my status code is "unknown status code: 12501". Not able to figure out the reason behind this.

Comment: is your SHA1 key entered correctly in the console?

Comment: also, have you added the google-services.json file to your `app/` directory?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [New Google sign in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33583326/new-google-sign-in-android)

Comment: @AshishRanjan yeah! I have added the SHA1 key in the console and even added the google-sevices.json file in the app directory, still the problem exists.

Answer (score 0):

```
    import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
    import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth;
    import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
    import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
    import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInResult;
    import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
    import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;
    import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
    import com.google.android.gms.common.api.OptionalPendingResult;
    import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
    import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
    import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
    import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

// ************************* GOOGLE *******************************
GoogleApiClient apiClient;
SignInButton btnSignIn;
//Button btnSignOut;
TextView txtNombre;
private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 1001;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private final Context mContext = this;
private CircleImageView mProfileImageView;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    txtNameGoogle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtNombreGoogle);
    imgPhotoGoogle = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgPhotoGoogle);

    // ************* GOOGLE **********************************
    btnSignOut= (Button) findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button);
    txtNombre   = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtNombreGoogle);
    btnSignIn = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
    mProfileImageView = (CircleImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgPhotoGoogle);
    //Google API Client
    GoogleSignInOptions gso =
            new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                    .requestEmail()
                    .build();
    apiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, this)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();

    //Personalización del botón de login
    btnSignIn.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_STANDARD);
    btnSignIn.setColorScheme(SignInButton.COLOR_AUTO);
    btnSignIn.setScopes(gso.getScopeArray());
    // *********************** Boton Google *****************************************
    btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(apiClient);
                startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
        }
    });
    btnSignOut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
        @Override   
        public void onClick(View v) {   
            Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(apiClient).setResultCallback(  
                    new ResultCallback<Status>() {  
                        @Override   
                        public void onResult(Status status) {   
                            updateUI(false);    
                        }   
                    }); 
        }   
    });
    updateUI(false);
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Error de conexion!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.e("GoogleSignIn", "OnConnectionFailed: " + connectionResult);
}
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result =
                Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);

        handleSignInResult(result);
    }
}

private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        //Usuario logueado --> Mostramos sus datos
        GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
        txtNombre.setText(acct.getDisplayName());
        //txtEmail.setText(acct.getEmail());
        //txtId.setText(acct.getId());
        //txtId.setText(acct.getPhotoUrl().toString());
        Uri uri = acct.getPhotoUrl();
        Picasso.with(mContext)
                .load(uri)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_pressed)
                .error(R.drawable.common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark)
                .into(mProfileImageView);
        updateUI(true);
    } else {
        //Usuario no logueado --> Lo mostramos como "Desconectado"
        updateUI(false);
    }
}
private void updateUI(boolean signedIn) {
    if (signedIn) {
        btnSignIn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        txtNombre.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mProfileImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        txtNombre.setText("Desconectado");
        mProfileImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_disabled);

        txtNombre.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mProfileImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btnSignIn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    OptionalPendingResult<GoogleSignInResult> opr = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn(apiClient);
    if (opr.isDone()) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = opr.get();
        handleSignInResult(result);
    } else {
        showProgressDialog();
        opr.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<GoogleSignInResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(GoogleSignInResult googleSignInResult) {
                hideProgressDialog();
                handleSignInResult(googleSignInResult);
            }
        });
    }
}

private void showProgressDialog() {
    if (progressDialog == null) {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("SignI-In");
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    }

    progressDialog.show();
}

private void hideProgressDialog() {
    if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
        progressDialog.hide();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please reword your explanation so that it is in English. Please read the SO guidelines before posting.