# google sign in works in android status code 12501

Tags: android, google-signin

**Status{statusCode=unknown status code: 12501, resolution=null}**

I'm trying to add google singin button on my app.
all conflagration done in app even place google-service.json file in app directory.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [New Google sign in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33583326/new-google-sign-in-android)

Comment: Did you add your `kestore.debug` `SHA` to google developer console? It's common mistake to add only the `release.keystore` but not the `debug.keystore`

Comment: how to add keystore.debug SHA in google developer console ?