# React Native Google Signin returns canceled if scope is google api for games

Tags: android, react-native, google-play-services, google-play-games

I am having some issues using react-native-google-signin package, specifically when adding the scope for games services  (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/games) it always fails with the 12501 code (canceled).

For example, this is a failing configuration:

```
GoogleSignin.configure({
  ...configPlatform,
  webClientId: 'clientid',
  offlineAccess: true,
  scopes: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/games"],
});
```

If I use a different scope from [auth google](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes), this configuration will let me login:

```
GoogleSignin.configure({
  ...configPlatform,
  webClientId: 'clientid',
  offlineAccess: true,
  scopes: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata"],
});
```

I have checked that the mobile image in the simulator I am using has play and google games installed. Due to this, I am not sure that the issue is on the package, or if I am configuring something wrong.

- Is there any extra permissions or similar I should add to my android project?
- Is there any extra scope that should be added and that is missing in conjunction with the games one?

[open issue with this similar content](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-google-signin/issues/499)

Comment: Based from this [link](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInStatusCodes#SIGN_IN_CANCELLED), this error means that the sign in was cancelled by the user. i.e. user cancelled some of the sign in resolutions, e.g. account picking or OAuth consent. Also from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33583326/new-google-sign-in-android), this may occur when there is a lack of Internet connectivity.

Comment: thanks for the response @abelita I don't think on my case is neither because i changed to other scope and worked meaning internet connection was ok. And also the user was me on simulator and I have given permissions to everything and no cancellation. In any case thanks for the leads.